# No se me actualizan los datos en mi base de datos

Tags: php, html, pdo

Hola tengo un problema no se actualiza los datos en mi base de datos
este es mi archivo update.php donde se actualizan los datos.
probé modificando las variables y el método de envio pero no se actualiza en la base de datos

> Actualizo el $sql pero lo mismo no me actualiza la base de datos

```
<?php
require('admincp/config.php');
require('function.php');
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$password = specialtext($_POST['password']);
$pais = specialtext($_POST['pais']);
$password = hash('sha512', $password);
$avatar = $_POST['avatar'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"rot","");
$data = [
    ':username' => $user,
    ':pais' => $pais
];
$sql = "UPDATE user SET usuario=$user,pasword=$password,tipo='user',avatar='default.png',bloqueado='0',verify='0',pais=$pais WHERE id=$id";
$stmt= $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);

header("Location: /");
 ?>
```

y este es mi formulario de donde envio los datos

```
<form action="update.php" method="post">
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">User</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="staticEmail" value="<?php echo $user;?>">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Pais</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="pais" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Pais" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row" style="display:none;"><!-- trabajando en esto -->
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Avatar</label>
              <input type="file" name="avatar" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
            </div>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Actualizar</button>
        </form>
```

Esta es mi tabla

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (<br>
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,<br>
  `usuario` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,<br>
  `pasword` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,<br>
  `tipo` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,<br>
  `avatar` varchar(2500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `bloqueado` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `verify` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,<br>
  `pais` varchar(2500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL<br>
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;<br>
```

Comment: Tu query para hacer el `update` esta mal.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: de la forma correcta tampoco me hace caso dado que tiene que atualizar al usuario en secion pero no lo actualiza

Comment: ayudaría mas en tu pregunta, si añades lo que estas obteniendo como resultado

Comment: @Max Hola, te recomiendo que elimines la pregunta y la vuelvas a crear eliminando de tu pregunta las claves de acceso a tu base de datos, una vez hecho esto cambia los datos de tu base de datos por favor y ten mas cuidado con eso la proxima vez. Un saludo.

Comment: Ops me olvide de eso ya cambie la clave

Comment: Si imprimes el $sql antes de enviarlo a ejecutar, sale la consulta que esperas?

Answer (score 1):

El query del update esta mal.

```
$sql = "UPDATE users SET usuario=:username,pais=:pais WHERE id=$id";
```

[Sentencia `UPDATE`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cuestiones:
1. chequea los name y lo que realmente queres enviar`<input type="text" **name="pais"** class="form-control" **id="inputPassword"** placeholder="Pais" value="">`

2.En tu script php lo estas esperando mediante POST pero no se envia desde el formulario.

3.Mostra que te retorna la ejecución de la query para saber cual es el error

Comment: Gracias por la información